# How to use Ajax ModalPopupExtender?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

> I had Ajax **ModalPopupExtender** task , I did everything well but when I
>   click **btnokay** as it fire event it didnot work and no event fired .

```
<asp:Panel ID="PostPanel" Style="display: none" runat="server">
    <div class="modalPopup">
        <div class="PopupBody">
            <p class="ads-text">
                Review your post first </p>
        </div>
        <div class="Controls">
            <div class="post">
                <asp:Button Text="OK" runat="server" ID="btnOkay" ValidationGroup="AddUserpopup"
                    OnClick="btnOkay_Click" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModelExtenderPost" runat="server" OkControlID="btnOkay"
    TargetControlID="HiddenField22" PopupControlID="PostPanel" PopupDragHandleControlID="PopupHeader"
    Drag="true" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField22" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add toolkitscriptmanager to master file or aspx file

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" />
```